# python how to get header from request

Tags: python, python-requests, csrf

Alright so, I am trying to get the "x-csrf-token" so I can send requests to a site and I only know how to do that in openbullet which is like this: <HEADERS(x-csrf-token)>.
Can someone help me?
I am using requests btw

Comment: If you don't provide any concrete details to your problem, the answers you'll get will be generic and no better than simply googling "python requests get header".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get CSRF token using python requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51351443/get-csrf-token-using-python-requests)

Comment: Are you using django, flask, fastAPI or any other framework / library?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.